# How to know when google credential has used a refresh token

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth

So I am implementing google drive into a application I am building. This application will be run on the client machine. After a user authenticates I am storing the refresh and access tokens in a google credential. However to prevent the user from having to authenticate every time they enter the app I plan on storing the access token and refresh token in a encrypted file.

***My question is***

How can I attach a listener to google credential to run every time the tokens are updated so I can update the tokens in the encrypted file.

I don't really want to have a separate thread just checking to see if the credential has changed, but if that the easiest way I can do it like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following documentation page on Data Stores: [Using OAuth 2.0 with the Google API Client Library for Java - Data store](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#data_store)

> Most applications will need to persist the credential's access token and/or refresh token. To persist the credential's access and/or refresh tokens, you can provide your own implementation of DataStoreFactory and DataStore with StoredCredential; or you can use one of the following implementations provided by the library:
>
> - JdoDataStoreFactory: persists the credential using JDO.
> - AppEngineDataStoreFactory: persists the credential using the Google App Engine Data Store API.
> - MemoryDataStoreFactory: "persists" the credential in memory, which is only useful as a short-term storage for the lifetime of the process.
> - FileDataStoreFactory: persists the credential in a file.
>
> ...
>
> You may use DataStoreCredentialRefreshListener and set it for the credential using GoogleCredential.Builder.addRefreshListener(CredentialRefreshListener).

Using the FileDataStoreFactory to store the tokens to a file will probably do the trick for you.

It will store the token to a file and takes care of storing the tokens when they have changed.